# Represent finite coordinates as an F# type

Tags: f#

I'm learning F# by implementing a board game engine. In accordance with the principle that invalid states should not be representable, I want to create a type which represents (x, y) coordinates (with x and y integers) where x and y **must** satisfy `0 <= x <= n` and `0 <= y <= m`. Creating an instance that does not satisfy those inequalities shouldn't compile. Is this possible?

Comment: Perhaps there's something usable here: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-non-strings

Comment: Thanks for the link :) I'd actually tried the same thing as what it suggests with it's NonNegativeInteger example, and it's not suitable because it's really just a union of a non-negative integer and None. I don't want board square coordinates to be potentially None for a few reasons, like having to pattern match on it everywhere in the code, and because it doesn't conceptually make sense for a coordinate to be None. I'd rather it not even be possible to create an instance that's not in the range.

Comment: F# doesn't support dependent types directly, but a few project exists that try to add them to language, [example](https://github.com/caindy/DependentTypesProvider)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think compile time assurances on values like this are possible.
I would handle this with a private constructor and the `Result` or `Option` type depending whether I wanted to propagate error information.

```
type Position = 
    private { 
        X: int
        Y: int
    }

    static member TryNew(x, y) = 
        if x >= 0 && x <= 10 then 
            if y >= 0 && y <=10 then 
                Ok {
                    X = x
                    Y = y
                }
            else
                Error $"Supplied y ({y}) must be between 0 and 10"
        else
            Error $"Supplied x ({x}) must be between 0 and 10"

module Position = 
    let moveX1 pos = 
        Position.TryNew(pos.X + 1, pos.Y)
```

This does create the issue where `Results` are now everywhere in your code but they don't have to be visible or cause you a lot of typing. This problem is precisely what computation expression libraries e.g. [FsToolkit.ErrorHandling](https://demystifyfp.gitbook.io/fstoolkit-errorhandling/) are designed to eliminate.

```
    let example = 
        result {
            let! start = Position.TryNew(0,0)
            let! next = start |> moveX1
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this that takes integers as input, but it can be done with a type that only provides integers as output:

```ml
type XCoord = X0 | X1 | X2 with

    member this.Int =
        match this with
            | X0 -> 0
            | X1 -> 1
            | X2 -> 2

    static member (-)(xa : XCoord, xb: XCoord) =
        xa.Int - xb.Int

type YCoord = Y0 | Y1 | Y2 with

    member this.Int =
        match this with
            | Y0 -> 0
            | Y1 -> 1
            | Y2 -> 2

    static member (-)(ya : YCoord, yb: YCoord) =
        ya.Int - yb.Int

type Point = MkPoint of (XCoord * YCoord) with

    member this.Ints =
        let (MkPoint (x, y)) = this
        x.Int, y.Int

    static member (-)((MkPoint (ax, ay)), (MkPoint (bx, by))) =
        ax - bx, ay - by

let ptA = MkPoint (X0, Y1)
let ptB = MkPoint (X2, Y0)
printfn "%A" ptA.Ints
printfn "%A" ptB.Ints
printfn "%A" (ptA - ptB)
```

I think this would be pretty clunky to use in practice, but it might work, depending on exactly what you want to do with it. I guess it's a case of "careful what you ask for".